# How to show symbol with 16h BIOS

Tags: assembly, x86, keyboard, nasm

This program has to get and show the symbol. But instead I have this strange array of strange symbols
org 100h

```
org 100h

section .text
_start:
    
    mov ah, 0     
    int 16h         

    mov [znak], al

    mov ah, 9   
    mov dx, znak     
    int 21h        

    mov ah, 4Ch         
    int 21h         

section .data
    znak db 0
```

[image: Output]

I tried to change syntax, but it doesnt work, or I just cant see that

Comment: Function 9h of int 21h expects string terminated with `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the DOS.PrintString function 09h (that requires the string to be terminated by a $ character), use the DOS.PrintCharacter function 02h:

```
mov  ah, 00h   ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
int  16h       ; -> AX
mov  dl, al
mov  ah, 02h   ; DOS.PrintCharacter     
int  21h       ; -> (AL)
mov  ax, 4C00h ; DOS.Terminate        
int  21h
```

Still want to use the DOS.PrintString function 09h?
Then

- make sure to setup the DS segment register
- terminate the string by a $ character

```
    mov  ax, @data
    mov  ds, ax
    mov  ah, 00h   ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
    int  16h       ; -> AX
    mov  [znak], al
    mov  dx, znak
    mov  ah, 09h   ; DOS.PrintString     
    int  21h       ; -> (AL)
    mov  ax, 4C00h ; DOS.Terminate        
    int  21h

section .data
    znak db 0, '$'
```

Comment: Looks like OP compiles into .com file (`.org 100h`). For .com files segment registers are already initialized at startup.

Comment: @dimich You're right! I overlooked that `org 100h`. Anyway, in case they're using .COM, I'd rather they not mention those `section .text` `_start:` `section .data` at all.

Comment: Yep. I'm not very familiar with nasm syntax but with tasm i've never used code/data segments separation for memory model tiny. Just compiled with nasm with and without section definitions - no difference except alignment.